# Правила "потому что"

Tags: запятые, правила

В предложении ***"Ты ставишь запятые потому что чувствуешь, где их ставить"*** должна ли стоять запятая перед ***"потому что"***?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая должна быть либо перед *"потому"*, либо перед *"что"*.

По общему правилу так:

```
> Ты ставишь запятые, потому что чувствуешь, где их ставить.
```

Если вы хотите поставить логическое ударение на первую часть составного союза, то так:

```
> Ты ставишь запятые потому, что чувствуешь, где их ставить.
```

Соответствующее правило [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_611).

Comment: Небольшая логическая ошибка: если не хочет подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение (оно всё так же падает), то тоже так. То есть надо: если на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение.

Comment: Да, верно. Спасибо. Исправил.